# Filtering in a association model under sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a form with different parameters and nested json, here the code:

```
{
"orderoptions": [
{
  "id": "10",
  "rdd": "20150108",
  "headerfieldconfigs": [
    {
      "propertyname": "name",
      "propertyvalue": "rdd",
      "required": "true",
      "hidden": "false",
      "propertyoptions": []
    },
    {
      "propertyname": "name",
      "propertyvalue": "poNr",
      "required": "false",
      "hidden": "false",
      "propertyoptions": []
    },
    {
      "propertyname": "name",
      "propertyvalue": "shipManually",
      "required": "false",
      "hidden": "false",
      "propertyoptions": []
    },
    {
      "propertyname": "name",
      "propertyvalue": "name",
      "required": "true",
      "hidden": "false",
      "propertyoptions": []
    },
    {
      "propertyname": "name",
      "propertyvalue": "region",
      "required": "true",
      "hidden": "false",
      "propertyoptions": [
        {
          "text": "Agriento",
          "value": "AG",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Alessandria",
          "value": "AL",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Ancona",
          "value": "AN",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Aosta",
          "value": "AO",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Arezzo",
          "value": "AR",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Ascoli Piceno",
          "value": "AP",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Asti",
          "value": "AT",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "San Marino",
          "value": "SM",
          "country": "SM"
        },
        {
          "text": "Bari",
          "value": "BA",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "BarlettaAndriaTrani",
          "value": "BT",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "Belluno",
          "value": "BL",
          "country": "IT"
        }],
    {
      "propertyname": "name",
      "propertyvalue": "country",
      "required": "true",
      "hidden": "false",
      "propertyoptions": [
        {
          "text": "Italy",
          "value": "IT",
          "country": "IT"
        },
        {
          "text": "San Marino",
          "value": "SM",
          "country": "SM"
        }
      ]
    }, 
]}
```

Concretely I have two selectfields called region and country and depending of the country you should select determinated regions in this example we have two countries, Italy and San Marino.
Here the store code with the associated model.

How to filter properly and I select Italy to see the Italy regions and so on... ??

```
Ext.define('OrderOption', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
requires: [
    'FieldConfig'
],

config: {
    useCache: false,
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        'id',
        'salesarea',
        'ordertype',
        'ordertypetext',
        'rdd'
    ],
    associations: [

        {
            type: 'hasMany',
            associatedModel: 'FieldConfig',
            ownerModel: 'OrderOption',
            name: 'headerfieldconfigs',
            associationKey: 'headerfieldconfigs'
        }

    ]
}
});
```

In the controller I have started the implementation but It is not  working properly..

```
    onShipManuallyCountryChange: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
    var store = Ext.getStore('OrderOptions');
    switch (newValue) {
        case 'SM' :
            this.getShipManuallyRegion().setValue(newValue);
            break;
        case 'IT' :
            this.getShipManuallyRegion().setValue('Agriento');
            break;
    }
    },
```

Any example??  thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue fully you would need to show the code for your stores and the form.

It's a while since I've used ST2, But I don't beleive that you can bind a components data on child data of a store. you have to apply the logic for this yourself.

I have created some sample code for you that should demonstrate how this can be approached, There are multiple ways of achieving this and mine may not be the best. But it does work.

I have simplified the data for demo purposes and used local array data.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        // create the models
        Ext.define('Country', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            config: {
                fields: [
                    { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
                ],
                associations: [{
                    type: 'hasMany',
                    associatedModel: 'Region',
                    ownerModel: 'Country',
                    primaryKey: 'id',
                    foreignKey: 'countryId',
                }]
            }
        });

        Ext.define('Region', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            config: {
                fields: [
                    { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'countryId', type: 'string' }
                ]
            }
        });


        var countries = [
            ["IT", "Italy"],
            ["SM", "San Marino"]
        ];

        var regions = [
            ["AG", "Agriento", "IT"],
            ["AL", "Alessandria", "IT"],
            ["AN", "Ancona", "IT"],
            ["AO", "Aosta", "IT"],
            ["AR", "Arezzo", "IT"],
            ["AP", "Ascoli Piceno", "IT"],
            ["AT", "Asti", "IT"],
            ["SM", "San Marino", "SM"],
            ["BA", "Bari", "IT"],
            ["BT", "BarlettaAndriaTrani", "IT"],
            ["BL", "Belluno", "IT"]    
        ];

        var countryStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            model: "Country",
            // store configs
            storeId: 'countryStore',
            data: countries
        });

        var regionStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            model: "Region",
            // store configs
            storeId: 'regionStore',
            autoLoad: false,
            data: regions
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Select',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    name: "countrySelect",
                    id: "countrySelectField",
                    displayField: "name",
                    valueField: "id",
                    label: 'Choose one',
                    store: countryStore,
                    autoSelect: false,
                    listeners: {
                        'change': function( select, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) {
                            regionStore.filter("countryId", newValue);
                        }
                    }
                }, {

                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    name: "regionSelect",
                    id: "regionSelectField",
                    displayField: "name",
                    valueField: "id",
                    autoSelect: false,
                    label: 'Choose one',
                    store: regionStore
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

I have also created a fiddle [HERE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fpk) using Sencha Fiddle which demonstrates this in use.

Bascially you listen to the change event and then apply a filter on the child store.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Here is an example of doing this with Nested Json, Although the JSON supplied is not valid, I would also recommend simplifying it:

```
// app.js
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function () {
        // create the models
        Ext.define('Country', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            config: {
                fields: [
                    { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
                ],
                associations: [{
                    type: 'hasMany',
                    associatedModel: 'Region',
                    ownerModel: 'Country',
                    primaryKey: 'id',
                    foreignKey: 'countryId',
                    associationKey: "regions"
                }]
            }
        });

        Ext.define('Region', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            config: {
                fields: [
                    { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'countryId', type: 'string' }
                ]
            }
        });

        var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
            // store configs
            autoDestroy: true,
            storeId: 'myStore',
            autoLoad:true,
            model: "Country",

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/data/data1.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'countries',
                    idProperty: 'id'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Select',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    name: "countrySelect",
                    id: "countrySelectField",
                    displayField: "name",
                    valueField: "id",
                    label: 'Choose one',
                    store: myStore,
                    autoSelect: false,
                    listeners: {
                        'change': function( select, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ) {
                            var country = select.getStore().getById(newValue);
                            console.log(country);
                            console.log(country.regions());
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});

// data/data1.json
{
  "countries": [{
    "id": "IT",
    "name":"Italy",
    "regions": [
      {"id":"AG", "name": "Agriento", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"AL", "name": "Alessandria", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"AN", "name": "Ancona", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"AO", "name": "Aosta", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"AR", "name": "Arezzo", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"AP", "name": "Ascoli Piceno", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"AT", "name": "Asti", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"BA", "name": "Bari", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"BT", "name": "BarlettaAndriaTrani", "countryId": "IT"},
      {"id":"BL", "name": "Belluno", "countryId": "IT"}
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "SM",
    "name":"San Marino",
    "regions": [
      {"id":"SM", "name": "San Marino", "countryId": "SM"}
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but Is not it possible to get data from country or region in my nested json??

Comment: You can load nested json into a store, yes. You could then get the currently selected record such as country and use getter functions such as `selectedCountry.getRegions()` to get the data but this cant automatically be used as a store. That nested data doesn't seem to match up with the models that you have?

Comment: in my initial example I would like to filter by ""propertyvalue": "region" and then visualize "propertyoptions" with the indicated regions..  my question is: How??   :-(

Comment: I have added @Scriptable my basic and very simple implementation on the controller

Comment: Could you provide your store and select field code?

Comment: Store is empty at the beginning and It´s created in the controller, selectfield is basic and it has xtype: selectfield, itemId: 'region', name: 'region', label: 'region'

Comment: From what I can see your json structure should follow your models structure. To load nested data you would use a store, in your case a [JsonStore](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore). This then loads the nested data into the store and the select field uses the store as the data source. It sounds like you are doing alot of this work manually which will cause you a number of issues further down the line. You should read up on the data layer of ST2 to get a better understanding. models hold a single record, Stores hold multiple, clever arrays basically

Comment: Could you please show me an example based in my nested json?  thanks!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68087/discussion-between-scriptable-and-inane).

Comment: Hi @inane, I've sent a chat invite via StackOverflow so that we dont clog the page with comments. Your JSON is not showing as valid when parsing through [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/). I would recommend simplifying your JSON